# Summing and comparing arrays in MongoDB

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm very new to mongodb, I've done simple stuff like storing and retrieving documents.

I have a collection of documents (thousands and growing) with and embedded array of integers (can be as large as 5000 integers) between 0 and 255

Example Mongo Collection Data:

```
{
  "name": "item1",
  "values": [1, 93, 45, 67, 89, 1, 2, 32, 45]
},
{
  "name": "item2",
  "values": [1, 23, 45, 123, 1, 5, 89, 14, 22]
},
{
  "name": "item3",
  "values": [23, 1, 44, 78, 89, 22, 150, 23, 12]
},
{
  "name": "item4",
  "values": [90, 23, 11, 67, 29, 1, 2, 1, 45]
}
```

Comparison would be:

```
pseudo code:

distance = 0

for a in passed_in_item
  for b in mongo_collection
    distance += a - b
  end
end
```

an example passed in array (same as the ones in the mongo document, they will always be the same length):

```
[1, 93, 45, 67, 89, 1, 2, 32, 45]
```

I'd like to pass in an array of integers as a query and difference it against the array in the document to find the one with the least difference. Is this the sort of thing map reduce is good at and how would I roughly go about it? An example would be great. Also eventually I'd like the passed in array to come from another document in Mongo in a different collection.

Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking here as to what does "comparing" mean to you an in fact what does "summing" have to do with this at all? Also not really clear "which" array is meant by "least difference". The one from the document or the one passed in or the "difference" array resulting? Also not really sure if you do indeed have an array with the same integer appearing possibly several times (as shown) or actually a "set". Probably best to show both data and the comparison and then the expected result. Then it is clear.

Comment: Sorry my apologies for not being clear, do the edits ive made help?

Comment: Still not clear on "passed in array" or an expected result from the sample given. You need to show this in your question. Give a sample array to "compare" and show the result you expect given both samples.

Comment: The passed in array is the same as the arrays in the document collection

Comment: Could you explain what the actual use case is? This is unusual and I'd like to know what your ultimate goal is to be sure there isn't some other way.

Comment: Ideally just need to find which array inside mongodb is the most similar to the provided input. eventually this uses euclidean distance to determine exactly how different the arrays are. Currently I'm pulling each of the values of out the database and running the calculation, wondered if MongoDB could possibly do it faster and save the round trips.

Comment: After further thought perhaps this is too specific a use case for SO.